# Spring Cloud 2020.x how to load Cloud Foundry environment variables

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-vault-config

Since the bootstrap context has been deprecated in 2020.x what is the recommended way to load Cloud Foundry environment variables. Do I still need to enable bootstrap support or can I just load them in application.yml? (doesn't seem to work for me)

For example my application.yml

```yaml
cloud:
    vault:
      authentication: TOKEN
      uri: ${vcap.services.hashicorp-vault.credentials.address}
      token: ${vcap.services.hashicorp-vault.credentials.auth.token}
      kv:
        backend: ${vcap.services.hashicorp-vault.credentials.backends.generic}
```

Cloud Foundry Error

```
2021-04-09T16:52:59.94+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 15:52:59.866 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
2021-04-09T16:52:59.94+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 1: ${vcap.services.hashicorp-vault.credentials.address}
2021-04-09T16:52:59.94+0100 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT at java.base/java.net.URI.create(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Bootstrap wasn't formally deprecated btw, it is just no longer the default. I'm unsure why those no longer resolve. Adding bootstrap is a valid workaround. I wonder if it is an ordering problem within boot. Do you have access to /actuator/env on another app in cf you could share?